# Do the pullback and restriction to the generic point coincide?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topologies

Assume we are given an etale sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on the big etale site of schemes over $S$. Let $X$ be a $S$ scheme with the structure morphism $j$ and let $i:\eta_X\hookrightarrow X$ be its generic point. Is it true that $(j\circ i)^*\mathcal{F}\simeq \mathcal{F}|_{\eta_X}$. The pullback means looking at $(j\circ i)^*\mathcal{F}$ as a sheaf on the small etale site of the generic point (after pullback in the big etale site). The sheaf ${F}|_{\eta_X}$ means restricting the values of $\mathcal{F}$ only to $\eta_X$ schemes (since $\eta_X$ schemes are $S$ schemes $\mathcal{F}$ has already some values defined for them.) and looking at it as a sheaf on the small etale site of $\eta_X$.

Generally pullback and restriction do not coincide unless that morphism is of finite type, I was wondering whether in the special case of the generic point or localization at a prime it is true.

Comment: You write "its generic point" – is $X$ irreducible? Of finite type over $X$? etc.

Comment: Sure yes, $X$ is irreducible and finite type over $S$.

Comment: I don't understand your terminology. What do you mean by restriction, if not pullback?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf on the big site which means it already has values for all $S$-schemes (not necessarily those that are finite type). So we can restrict it to the small site of every $S$ scheme. (Now after thinking I believe these do not necessarily coincide.)

Comment: The small site of $S$ is a subsite of the large site of $S$, yes. The small site of $\eta_X$ (or $X$, or whatever) is not necessarily a subsite of the large site of $S$, so you can't literally restrict in that case. Putting that aside, what do you mean by $i^* F$? $F$ is a sheaf on $S$, but $i$ is a morphism to $X$ so you need to turn $F$ into a sheaf on $X$ first.

Comment: $\eta_X$ and any scheme on it is an $S$ scheme so their values are already defined in $\mathcal{F}$, so it seems if you have a sheaf on the big etale site of $S$ you can get a sheaf on the small etale site of $\eta_X$.

Comment: It is not literally true that $\eta_X$-schemes are $S$-schemes – the structure morphisms are different. Every $\eta_X$-scheme can be turned into an $S$-scheme by postcomposing $j \circ i$, of course, but generally this process changes the morphisms between the objects. So, yes, you can "restrict" a sheaf on the big site of $S$ to a sheaf on (the big or small site of) $\eta_X$ but I would call this operation pullback. If this is what you mean then both of the operations you are thinking about are pullback and are therefore literally the same.

Comment: Perhaps what you are really thinking about is this: take $j^* F$ and restrict it to the small site of $X$, then pullback along $i$ to the small site of $\eta_X$; is this different from taking $(j \circ i)^* F$ and then restricting to the small site of $\eta_X$?

Comment: That wasn't what I had in my mind but that could be another question. But what I said makes sense for certain sheaves. For example for $\mathcal{G}_m$, how is that it only makes sense for certain sheaves, I'm confused at the moment.